# Concatenation of two arrays using while loop

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop, concatenation

There is no problem with the code. I have a doubt whether we can concatenate two arrays or not. We learned that we cannot increase the size of an array once it is declared. But the following code seems to be doing that. Can we add elements to the statically created arrays using bellow part?

> while(S1[i] = S2[j]) {
>             i++;
>             j++;
>           }

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* strcatt(char[], char[]);

int main(void) {
    char S1[] = "University of Colombo";
    char S2[] = "Sri Lanka";
    printf("%s\n", strcatt(S1, S2));
return 0;
}

char* strcatt(char S1[], char S2[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(S1[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    S1[i++] = ' ';
    while(S1[i] = S2[j]) {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
return (S1);
}
```

I get this output :- University of Colombo Sri Lanka

Comment: You should allocate some new memory and then copy the chars into it.

Comment: @Chamika The code has undefined behavior because there are attempts to write in memiry beyond an array.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen thanx for the comment. But my problem is how can we extend an array once it is declared as i shown here? After the null value of the first array it takes the elements of the other array using the second while loop. In here the first array has extended.

Comment: @Chamika The code will be valid provided that the first array is declared at least like char S1[32] = "University of Colombo"; That is if the first array has enough memory to accomodate elements of the second array

Comment: You cannot extend it, you should use something like `char* result = new char[totalSize];` to create a new one inside the strcat function. You'll need to check the length of both strings + 1. Then you can copy the chars like the second loop `while(result[i] = S2[j])` etc

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanx for replying. I didn't get any kind of error or warning. And it's giving me the correct result. So how can it be invalid?

Comment: It might give the correct result. You're writing to memory which isn't allocated for you. Maybe now it will work, but anyway/anywhere an *access violation* can pop up and will be hard to find.

Comment: C does not control your code, it is up to you! Likewise, C does not check if you reached end of an array, it is your responsibility to do that. So the behavior is really undefined, you are just writing to a memory location which is not allocated to your array.

Answer (score 1):

The function itself is correct except it should be updated the following way

```
char * strcatt( char s1[], const char s2[] ) 
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    while ( s1[i] ) i++;

    s1[i++] = ' ';

    while ( s1[i] = s2[j] ) 
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    return s1;
}
```

That is the type `int` of the variables `i` and `j` should be changed to the type `size_t` because the size of an array can be greater than the meximum positive value of an object of the type `int`.

And the second parameter should be qualified as `const` because it is not changed by the function. Otherwise at least you will not be able to call the function for a constant character array passed to the function as the second argument even it is not changed in the function.

But nevertheless the program has undefined behavior because the character array `S1` has no space to accomodate the string stored in the second array `S2`.

The program will be valid if the first character array will have at least 32 or more elements

```
char S1[32] = "University of Colombo";
```

That is if the size of the array will be equal to or greater than `sizeof( "University of Colombo" ) + sizeof( "Sri Lanka" )`

Take into account that undefined behavior means everything including even the expected result.:) But it also means that the corresponding code is invalid.

In case of your program there are attempts to write to memory beyond the character array `S1`.

It occurred such a way that the compiler placed the two arrays immediately one after another in the order S1 and then S2. So in fact the function strcatt overwrited the character array S2 by itself.

But it is not necessary that another compiler will place the arrays in this order and moreover without a gap between the character arrays.

Comment: "The function itself is correct except it should be updated the following way" --- this is mostly style suggestions, right? I think it would be good to make it clear if so. In addition, style guides can be subjective.

Comment: @ImperishableNight It is not a question about style. For starters if the second parameter is not declared as const then you will not be able to call the function for a constant character array though it is not changed in the function. And moreover the user of the function can not be sure that the function dies not change the second argument. And also the size of a character array can be greater than the maximum value stored in an object of the type int.

Comment: I see. It might be good to clarify in that case, too. It can be hard to see the two changes, especially when you also make style changes (in particular, I find your extensive use of empty lines distracting).

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the function is wrong as you do not have enough space for the second string. Usually such a functions allocate memory themselves or get the buffer as the additional parameter. Below you two versions one allocates the memory, the second one takes the buffer. If the buffer is null it allocates the memory for the new string. You need to free it when not needed

```
char *strcpyt(char *dest, const char *str)
{
    char *result = dest;
    if(dest && str)
    {
        while(*dest++ = *src++);
    }
    return result;
}

size_t strlent(const char *str)
{
    const char *start = str;
    size_t length = 0;

    if(str)
    {
        while(*str++);
        length = str - start - 1;
    }
    return length;
}

char *strcatt1(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{   
    char *result = NULL; 
    size_t size;
    if(str1 && str2)
    {
        result = malloc((size = strlent(str1)) + strlent(str2) + 1);
        if(result)
        {
            strcpyt(result, str1);
            strcpyt(result + size, str2);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char *strcatt2(char *buff, const char *str1, const char *str2)
{   
    char *result = buff; 
    size_t size;
    if(str1 && str2)
    {
        if(!result)
        {
            result = malloc((size = strlent(str1)) + strlent(str2) + 1);
        }
        if(result)
        {
            strcpyt(result, str1);
            strcpyt(result + size, str2);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```